# Handling up/down votes on social news website

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to make a reddit-like web application from scratch.
I'm not sure how to store the up and down votes.

I'm thinking about creating a table called 'user_votes'
with fields 'id', 'user_id', 'voted_link_id', 'up_or_down'

So it's basically adding a row for "who voted what on what" every time a user votes.

I'm inserting a new row instead of just adding 1, because the user profile page will have to show the list of links the user voted. So I need to keep track of every single votes. But I don't feel like it's efficient.

I'm not familiar with web applications heavily relying on DB.
Please guide me.

P.S.
Which columns should be indexed?

Comment: I think you'd be much better served by doing a more basic project first.

Comment: Suggest a better title: `Hnadling up/down votes on social news website.`  Sounds like you want someone to help you write the entire thing from scratch.

Comment: @mellamokb: Done.
@Tyler: I've done some CMS. I like the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you want both.

You must have the table with Article_ID, User_ID, +1 or -1. This is for exactly the reasons you've stated. You'll need to show a user's votes as a running account. You'll also us that to ensure uniqueness.

You now have to think about frequency. Articles will be viewed more frequently than voted on. Because of that, you'd have to do a lot of SUMs on the Vote table that result in the exact same values being produced.

Instead you should keep two counters on the Article table: a total of upvotes and a total of downvotes. The reason for two is that, the sum is inconsequential since the two values are on the same row. Second you may want to implement something that will expose those values like SO does. (You can't see that until you get so many points (about 1500)).

You may want to show a list of articles and the total points each has... you don't want to SUM over the votes table for a long list of articles. You also may want to allow people to set limits on articles, "only show me over +10". Again, you don't want to sum over the votes table every time someone opens their home page.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's good you like the challenge!

Secondly, I'd suggest not optimizing the application until you can prove you need to, esp. in the database design. It's a fine balance, but broadly speaking, I'd go for a "pure" relational design first, and only introduce duplicated data when you really, really have to.

So, I'd start by recording each vote, and calculating the total score on the fly. This way, you don't need to deal with what happens when your "calculated score" gets out of sync with the votes (e.g. because the application failed between writing the vote and updating the total).

Once you have that design working, find a way to test performance, with huge volumes of data, and large volumes of visitors. DBMonster and Apache JMeter may be the tools to use here.

When you bump into performance issues, try to solve them through query optimization and indexing first - use Stack Exchange to it's fullest! Also look at application level caching.

When you really, really can't squeeze any more performance out of the application, I'd start pre-calculating the scores in the way Stephanie suggests.

Comment: I completely agree that premature optimization is the death knell of many projects. OTOH, This is a very well understood pattern and I don't think there's much if any harm in keeping the running totals. You know that the score will need to be shown a lot and changed infrequently, precalculation is practically required.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably about the best design if you want to be able to track where all the votes went and make sure nobody can vote multiple times on the same article.  Properly indexed, a table even with a couple of million rows is nothing.  Though you will want to be wise with caching in your application to help performance.